# Sequelize.build with associations

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm creating a multipage survey with Node.js 6, Express.js 4 and Sequelize 4.4.2. While the user fills out the survey several model objects are build, but not persisted, this will not happen until the survey is completely done.

Some of these models are associated with each other and I want to know if it's possible to use the .build() function of an defined model with initial values (such as "name" or "address") as well as an previously build but not persisted model object.

Maybe a simple example, what I mean:

```
const comp = Company.build({
    Name: 'My Company',
    Location: 'Ireland',
    Employees: [] // Employee would be another model in this case
});
```

It seems, that Employees is ignored while the obejct is built. Is there a way to attach properties which are NOT defined as field for the model (in this case: Company) but as association?

Hope you got, what I mean ...

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself! I just append the built models after to the dataValues property of the previously built model object and not directly whilst the build process.